# Convert column name to time

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, varchar, unpivot

There is a table `TABLE` which stores values for various intervals of time in a given day. The day can be divided in to 24 intervals of an hour each or 96 intervals of 15 mins duration each. `TABLE` contains the following columns

```
DATE
INTERVALCOUNT
INT001
INT002
.
.
INT096
```

I need to display the values in the table in the following format where based on the `INTERVALCOUNT` value the time is calculated and its associated value is displayed

SAMPLE OUTPUT

```
DATE        TIME             INTERVALCOUNT  VALUE
2013-04-11  00:00:00.0000000        96      23.43
2013-04-11  00:15:00.0000000        96      26.91
2013-04-11  00:30:00.0000000        96      28.1999999999
2013-04-11  00:45:00.0000000        96      28.77
2013-04-23  00:00:00.0000000        24      18.3099999999
2013-04-23  01:00:00.0000000        24      20.94
```

CODE

```
SELECT   [DATE],
        (CASE 
        WHEN [INTERVALCOUNT]=96 THEN CAST(DATEADD(MINUTE,CAST(SUBSTRING([INTERVAL],4,3) AS INT)*15, [DATE]) AS Time)
        WHEN [INTERVALCOUNT]=24 THEN CAST(DATEADD(HOUR,CAST(SUBSTRING([INTERVAL],4,3) AS INT), [DATE]) AS Time)
        END) AS [TIME],
        [INTERVALCOUNT], --24/96 
        [VALUE] 
        FROM ( SELECT [DATE],
            [INTERVALCOUNT], --24/96 
            [INT001], [INT002], [INT003], [INT004], [INT005], [INT006], [INT007], [INT008], 
            [INT009], [INT010], [INT011], [INT012], [INT013], [INT014], [INT015], [INT016],
            [INT017], [INT018], [INT019], [INT020], [INT021], [INT022], [INT023], [INT024],
            [INT025], [INT026], [INT027], [INT028], [INT029], [INT030], [INT031], [INT032],
            [INT033], [INT034], [INT035], [INT036], [INT037], [INT038], [INT039], [INT040], 
            [INT041], [INT042], [INT043], [INT044], [INT045], [INT046], [INT047], [INT048],
            [INT049], [INT050], [INT051], [INT052], [INT053], [INT054], [INT055], [INT056],
            [INT057], [INT058], [INT059], [INT060], [INT061], [INT062], [INT063], [INT064],
            [INT065], [INT066], [INT067], [INT068], [INT069], [INT070], [INT071], [INT072], 
            [INT073], [INT074], [INT075], [INT076], [INT077], [INT078], [INT079], [INT080],
            [INT081], [INT082], [INT083], [INT084], [INT085], [INT086], [INT087], [INT088], 
            [INT089], [INT090], [INT091], [INT092], [INT093], [INT094], [INT095], [INT096] 
            FROM          [TABLE] ) [Source]
        UNPIVOT ([VALUE] FOR [INTERVAL] IN
        ([INT001], [INT002], [INT003], [INT004], [INT005], [INT006], [INT007], [INT008], 
        [INT009], [INT010], [INT011], [INT012], [INT013], [INT014], [INT015], [INT016],
        [INT017], [INT018], [INT019], [INT020], [INT021], [INT022], [INT023], [INT024],
        [INT025], [INT026], [INT027], [INT028], [INT029], [INT030], [INT031], [INT032],
        [INT033], [INT034], [INT035], [INT036], [INT037], [INT038], [INT039], [INT040], 
        [INT041], [INT042], [INT043], [INT044], [INT045], [INT046], [INT047], [INT048],
        [INT049], [INT050], [INT051], [INT052], [INT053], [INT054], [INT055], [INT056],
        [INT057], [INT058], [INT059], [INT060], [INT061], [INT062], [INT063], [INT064],
        [INT065], [INT066], [INT067], [INT068], [INT069], [INT070], [INT071], [INT072], 
        [INT073], [INT074], [INT075], [INT076], [INT077], [INT078], [INT079], [INT080],
        [INT081], [INT082], [INT083], [INT084], [INT085], [INT086], [INT087], [INT088], 
        [INT089], [INT090], [INT091], [INT092], [INT093], [INT094], [INT095], [INT096]) ) [Unpivot]
```

I have achieved it by using `UNPIVOT` and  for displaying the time is use `CAST` along with `SUBSTRING`. Is there a better way of doing this? especially the part where I convert the intervals to time.

**EDIT** The table design can't be changed

Comment: The best way to do this will be to change your table design to something more normalized, like `Date, Int, Value`...

Comment: I can't change the table design as I an intern and this is being used by the company for the last 3-4 years

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a better way of doing this?

Depends on what you mean by *better*. For instance, the following expression for `TIME` calculation is "better" in terms of the amount of code:

```
DATEADD(
  MINUTE,
  CAST(SUBSTRING([INTERVAL],4,3) AS INT) * 1440 / INTERVALCOUNT,
  CAST('00:00' AS time)
) AS [TIME]
```

You might also find it more scalable (in fact, *actually* scalable): if you needed to add support for, say, half-hour intervals, you would only need to start using `INTERVALCOUNT = 48` with your data.

At the same time, the intent may be conveyed in a less clear way with the above code. Therefore, if `24` and `96` are the only possible values you can ever need for `INTERVALCOUNT`, you will probably not need any more flexibility than what you've got already for that part of your code.

Comment: better in the sense I feel the `CASE`, two `CAST` operations and adding the `DATE` column might be not be required. getting rid of some of them could make the code faster and efficient as there are close to 2,700,000 rows. `INTERVALCOUNT` as of now has only two values 24 and 96. Thanks for the more generic solution and for getting rid of case

Answer (score 0):

You haven't mentioned what the purpose of the output is but I assume it's some sort of report?

I don't think there is a better way of doing this. What you have there is a classic use case for UNPIVOT and your solution seems appropriate to me, given that you can't change the underlying data structure.

Comment: Yes, it is for a report

Answer (score 0):

Try this one -

```
DECLARE 
      @cols NVARCHAR(MAX)
    , @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @cols = STUFF((
    SELECT ', [' + c.name + ']'
    FROM sys.columns c
    WHERE c.name LIKE 'INT%'
        AND c.[object_id] = OBJECT_ID('dbo.TABLE')
    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'VARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 2, '')

SELECT @SQL = '

SELECT 
      [DATE]
    , [TIME] = CASE 
        WHEN [INTERVALCOUNT] = 96 
            THEN CAST(DATEADD(MINUTE, CAST(SUBSTRING([INTERVAL],4,3) AS INT)*15, [DATE]) AS Time)
        WHEN [INTERVALCOUNT] = 24 
            THEN CAST(DATEADD(HOUR, CAST(SUBSTRING([INTERVAL],4,3) AS INT), [DATE]) AS Time)
      END
    , [INTERVALCOUNT]
    , [VALUE] 
FROM ( 
    SELECT [DATE], [INTERVALCOUNT], ' + @cols + ' 
    FROM [TABLE] 
) s
UNPIVOT ([VALUE] FOR [INTERVAL] IN (' + @cols + ') ) up
'

PRINT @SQL
EXEC sys.sp_executesql @SQL
```

Comment: When I run it I get "query executed successfully" with no output.

Comment: Check your table name in `OBJECT_ID(...)`.